# Is there a Babel transformer for applying JSX attributes in a shorthand way?

Tags: babeljs, jsx

In my code, I had a lot of components which looks like

```
function AddressInput(props) {
 const { error, value, onChange, hints } = props;
 return (
   <CustomInput  error={error}  onChange={onChange}  value={value} hints={hints} />
 );
}
```

I don't want to use `<CustomInput ...props>` notation because the first variant allows to filter props for widely used components. 
What I want, it's to pass component props in a shorter way, maybe like:

```
const { error, value, onChange, hints } = props;
<CustomInput :error :onChange :value :hints />
```

Is there any babel transformers which can provide such ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No additional babel plugin is necessary. You can use shorthand property names + spread operator.

Example:

```
function AddressInput(props) {
  const { error, value, onChange, hints } = props;
  return (<CustomInput {...{error, value, onChange, hints}} />);
}
```

Not the most concise syntax, but it might be improved in the future. See the [GitHub discussion thread](https://github.com/facebook/jsx/issues/23).